# How to automatically restart systemd service if file is changed?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have a `systemd` service which uses a custom file to start a program on a embedded-Linux device. I want to start this service automatically when the file is modified/changed. While reading `systemd` manual, I came across a solution which uses `.path` unit file do this. My setup is shown below:

`test.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp
After=network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/data/test
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myapp -c /data/test/myconfig.cfg

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have created a `test-restart.service` file with contents:

```
[Service]
Type=OneShot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart test.service
```

Also, a `test-restart.path` unit file:

```
[Path]
Unit=test-restart.service
PathChanged=/data/test/myconfig.cfg 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But, as far as I understood, I need to execute `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` and this will trigger if file is modified and then `test-restart.service` is activated which will restart `test.service`. But, I am not sure how to call this `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` automatically? I mean, should I manually execute this every time (or maybe for only first time?) or is this handled by `systemctl`? And what happens if the device is rebooted? Should we call `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` again manually?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

- `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` sets the boot up automatically.
- It adds a soft link to the specified boot level.
- It is a persistent behavior
- It will start when `systemd` starts
- You can look at its reverse dependencies `systemctl list-dependencies test-restart.path --reverse`
- No need to manually execute `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` again
- device reboot is only needed once
- `test-restart.path` will start itself when the system starts

Comment: Hello, thank you for the update. If I understand correctly, whenever I add a new `test-restart.path` file, device needs to be just rebooted to make it work. And no need to call `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path`. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're welcome | basically | there may be some errors | you don't need to reboot the unit at any time | after creating the `test-restart.path` `systemd path unit` | you only need to run `systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` once and that's it. You don't need to restart the system, and you don't need to execute any commands that will trigger a restart of the service after `/data/test/myconfig.cfg `

Comment: ` systemctl enable --now test-restart.path` means start it | and set it to start automatically | is a simple way to write ` systemctl start test-restart.path && systemctl enable test-restart.path` | ` systemctl enable test-restart.path` is a command that satisfies idempotency.